# Error accessing jQuery(window).height() in jasmine while running tests in maven

Tags: maven, window, jasmine

In order to increase test coverage of my project, I'm starting to build tests for existing JS code.

One of the existing modules puts the window height in a variable with jQuery:
    var window_height = jQuery(window).height();
Internally jQuery uses the clientHeight property.

Now with either **mvn clean install** or **mvn -o test** I'm getting the error:
*Cannot read property "clientHeight" from null*

I assume this is because the "virtual browser" that Jasmine creates doesn't have the window property. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: btw, when I run **mvn jasmine:bdd** and check the test results in the browser (localhost:8234) there are no problems...

Comment: Could you create a fake 'window' object in a 'Before' method, and set the clientHeight property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Derek for your answer, the idea of overwriting jQuery.height did the trick, but not in a spy.

```
(function(){
  $.prototype.height = function() {
    var original = $.prototype.height;

    if (this[0] === window) {
      return 800; // Return mock window height
    } else {
      return original.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  } 
})();
```

In the pom.xml I include this file directly after jQuery in the .

Comment: This works, but Derek's suggestion is a much better approach. Spies/stubs exist explicitly to prevent you from needing to add test code to your production code. A bad practice for many reasons...

Answer (score 8):

I can't vouch for how safe it is to override jQuery's methods, but here's how you can use jasmine's `spyOn` function to override what $(window).height() returns.

```
it("can override jquerys height function", function() {
  var original = $.prototype.height;
  spyOn($.prototype, 'height').andCallFake(function() {
    if (this[0] === window) {
      return 5;  // whatever you want the window height to appear to be
    } else {
      return original.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  });

  // window height gets overridden
  expect($(window).height()).toEqual(5);

  // everything else uses the actual jQuery call
  expect($("body").height()).toBeGreaterThan(5);
});
```

Alternatively, it would be safer create your own getWindowHeight() function somewhere and just `spyOn` that with a fake.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem starts before the executing of the specs though..
The problem rises in one of the source scripts, which on init gets the height of the window.
I could use your answer though, by overwriting the jQuery.height property like you suggested, but then in the global scope, not in a spy. Upvote for the suggestion!